# CiviCRM Search page results - Custom template

Tags: civicrm-home, search-results, custom

Thank you in advance. I am looking for a way to create custom search result pages (perhaps through Smarty ?).

We have heavily customised CiviCRM to work for our organisation needs and most of the information you get on a search like address, city, state, country, phone etc. are of no use for us.

Just to clarify I am not asking on how to create a report to do something. I want / need to know if there is a way to modify the search result page itself by being able to change the columns that appear there.

Thank you again.

Best A.

Answer (score 3):

It depends which searches you are talking about, but you can configure a Profile for displaying contact search results at `Administer > Customize Data & Screens > Search Preferences > Default Contact Search Profile` or at the top of an Advanced Search page.

You might also want to investigate SearchKit and Form Builder.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for comming back. When you do Search -> Find Contacts. The resulting page for that brings back the following fields: Name, Address, City, State, Postal, Country, Email, Phone. I would like to change these columns to something like Name, Nickname, Contact subtype and so on. Event maybe include some of the custom fields we've created for out needs.